# Problema em fazer um campo buscar por data e id

Tags: php, laravel, algoritmo-de-busca

Fiz um campo *search* porém não estou conseguindo fazer buscas pela data e nem por id.

O banco de dados que uso é o Postgres, estou usando framework Laravel 5.2

```
public function scopeSearchByKeyword($query, $keyword)
{
   if ($keyword!='') {

        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where("nome_problema", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                  ->orWhere("id", "LIKE", "%$keyword")
                  ->orWhere("data_criacao", "LIKE", "%$keyword");
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: `$keyword` o que pode vir de conteúdo nessa variável? explicite na sua pergunta os valores possiveis?

Answer (score 0):

O método "where" aparenta ter sido escrito errado, tente assim:

```
public function scopeSearchByKeyword($query, $keyword)
{
   if ($keyword!='') {

        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where("nome_problema", "LIKE", "%" .$keyword. "%")
                  ->orWhere("id", "LIKE", "%" .$keyword. "%")
                  ->orWhere("data_criacao", "LIKE", "%" .$keyword. "%");
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```